# Linker complaining about “unresolved external symbol”

Tags: c++, linker-errors

- [Full code of `sequence_test.cpp`](http://pastebin.com/vQj5phQ0) (test debugger driver)
- [Full code of `sequence2.cpp`](http://pastebin.com/HivcpmCq) (implementation file)

This is the header file code

```
#ifndef SEQUENCE_H
#define SEQUENCE_H
#include <cstdlib>  // Provides size_t

namespace CISP430_A2
{
    class sequence
    {
    public:
        // TYPEDEFS and MEMBER CONSTANTS
        typedef double value_type;
        typedef size_t size_type;
        enum { CAPACITY = 30 };
        // CONSTRUCTOR
        sequence(size_type entry=CAPACITY )
        {
            for(int i=0;i<CAPACITY;i++)
                data[i]=0;
            used=0;
            capacity=CAPACITY;
            current_index=0;
        }
           // COPY CONSTRUCTOR
        sequence(const sequence& entry);       
    // Library facilities used: cstdlib
        // MODIFICATION MEMBER FUNCTIONS
        void start( );
        void advance( );
        void insert(const value_type& entry);
        void attach(const value_type& entry);
        void remove_current( );
        void resize(size_type new_capacity);
        void sequence::operator =(const sequence& entry);
        // CONSTANT MEMBER FUNCTIONS
        size_type size( ) const;
        bool is_item( ) const;
        value_type current( ) const;
        //Destructor
         ~sequence(){}
    private:
        value_type data[CAPACITY];
        size_type used;
        size_type capacity;
        size_type current_index;
    };
}

#endif
```

I am currently getting this linker error:

> sequence_test.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "`public: __thiscall                  CISP430_A2::sequence::sequence(unsigned int)`" (??0sequence@CISP430_A2@@QAE@I@Z) referenced in function `_main`

Comment: Is the file you posted `sequence2.h`, not `sequence.h`?

Comment: Next time, please produce a *minimal* complete example to showcase the problem. Nobody likes trawling through dozens of lines of irrelevant code.

Comment: well i've been asked for entire source codes before to diagnose the problem so i wanted to include all three files just in case. and i dont know what the problem is.. which is why i posted the code.

Comment: please strip down everything that is not needed to demonstrate the problem. People will only ask for the complete code, when you leave out something that is needed to explain the problem - nobody will ask, if you show a minimal & complete portion of code.

Comment: ok, it compiles: http://ideone.com/XjgrI

Comment: but i dont know what part of my code isnt needed to demonstrate this problem.. i dont what part of my code could possibly be making this problem.. i posted the linker error that is minimal and complete in hopes maybe someone else could figure it out by looking at it...

Comment: thanks xjgrl i just made a whole new project and copied the codes into new files and got it to run.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried and compiled your files sucessfully, so it's not in your code (at least not in the parts you posted)

I suppose, you're using Visual Studio? Try the following

- Make sure your project settings are correct (all files included in your project?)
- Do you use precompiled headers? Try to turn them off.
- Try a clean rebuild.